# Simple Redux Counter Component implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement a counter component using simple Redux , have created the `store` using `createStore` and used `store.dispatch`

complete code :

```js
/*==================================================
This is only to format the code, I have used this editor, 
you can scroll down for the fiddle having error.
==================================================*/


 const createStore = Redux.createStore;

 const counter = (state = {
     counter: 0
 }, action) => {
     console.log('counter', state)
     switch (action.type) {
         case 'INCREMENT':
             return state.counter + 1;
         case 'DECREMENT':
             return state.counter - 1;
         default:
             return state;
     }
 }

 const store = createStore(counter);

 let Counter = React.createClass({
     getInitialState() {
         return store.getState()
     },

     incrementCounter() {
         store.dispatch({
             type: 'INCREMENT'
         });
     },
     decrementCounter() {
         store.dispatch({
             type: 'DECREMENT'
         });
     },

     render() {

         console.log('NEW STATE:', store.getState(), this.state)
         return (
              <div>
                <p>{this.state.counter}</p>
                <div>
                <button onClick={this.incrementCounter}>+</button>
                <button onClick={this.decrementCounter}>-</button>
                </div>
              </div>
      ) 
     }

 })

 ReactDOM.render( < Counter / > , document.getElementById('container'))
```

[DEMO JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/63114/)

MY issue : I am not able to get the **updated** store value in the render block when I click on `incrementCounter` and `decrementCounter` functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several issues

1. You need ***subscribe*** for state changes, it is important, because your component does not know about new state
2. `state` is `Object`, you have to return from `counter` `Object`, in your example you return `Number` in `INCREMENT` and `DECREMENT`

```js
const createStore = Redux.createStore;

const counter = (state = {
  counter: 0
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { counter: state.counter + 1 });
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { counter: state.counter - 1 });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = createStore(counter);

let Counter = React.createClass({
  incrementCounter() {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' });
  },
  
  decrementCounter() {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' });
  },

  render() {
    return <div>
      <p>{ this.props.value }</p>
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.incrementCounter}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrementCounter}>-</button>
      </div>
    </div> 
  }
})

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    // get updated state value, and pass it to component
    <Counter value={ store.getState().counter } />, 
    document.getElementById('container')
  )
};

store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Note**: for `React`, `Redux` ([`react-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux)) provides component called `Provider`, and you don't need use `store.subscribe`, however under the hood logic similar as in my example

**Update:**

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, bindActionCreators } = Redux;

// Component 
let Counter = ({ value, onIncrement, onDecrement }) => (
  <div>
    <p>{ value }</p>
    <div>
      <button onClick={ onIncrement }>+</button>
      <button onClick={ onDecrement }>-</button>
    </div>
  </div> 
);

// Reducer
const counter = (state = {
  counter: 0
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return { ...state, counter: state.counter + 1 };
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return { ...state, counter: state.counter - 1 };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

// actions
const onIncrement = () => {
  return { type: 'INCREMENT' }
}

const onDecrement = () => {
  return { type: 'DECREMENT' }
};

// map state and actions
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    value: state.counter
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return bindActionCreators(
    { onIncrement, onDecrement }, 
    dispatch
  );
}

Counter = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Counter);

const store = createStore(counter);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={ store }>
    <Counter />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/4.4.6/react-redux.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: As Alexander has done here, your reducer also needed to use Object.assign as it was returning an integer (the new count) rather than the state object as defined as your initial state, eg { counter: 1 }.

Comment: @alexander-t, Thank you for the help. and I really appreciate if you can also give me a `Provider` example too. please........

Comment: @AlexanderT. you are awesome thanks, can you please also tell me some thing with events, I mean in plain html+JS we write as onclick=somethg(), this is execute only when you click of the particular element, but in react we should not write like `onclick=somethg()`, it should be like `onclick={somethg}` without ( and )

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is this:

```
const counter = (state = {
     counter: 0
 }, action) => {
     console.log('counter', state)
     switch (action.type) {
         case 'INCREMENT':
             return state.counter + 1;
         case 'DECREMENT':
             return state.counter - 1;
         default:
             return state;
     }
 }
```

especially this lines:

```
         case 'INCREMENT':
             return state.counter + 1;
         case 'DECREMENT':
             return state.counter - 1;
```

What are you returning? A NUMBER! But your state shape is an object `{counter: Number}`

So you have to return a new object like this:

```
         case 'INCREMENT':
             return {counter: state.counter + 1}
         case 'DECREMENT':
             return {counter: state.counter - 1}
```

The above changes should fix it.
To be more flexible within your reducer, you should assign the new object, to the existing state like this:

```
         case 'INCREMENT':
             return {
                ...state,
                counter: state.counter + 1
             }
         case 'DECREMENT':
             return {
                ...state,
                counter: state.counter - 1
             }
```